# Sending mail with PHP application deployed on Google App Engine

Tags: php, google-app-engine, email

I am trying to send email from my PHP application deployed on GAE but unable to send.

My PHP code:

```
<?php
use google\appengine\api\mail\Message;

$name=$email=$query="";

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST"){

   $name = $_POST["name"];
   $email = $_POST["email"];
   $query = $_POST["query"];

  require_once 'google/appengine/api/mail/Message.php';
    $mail_options = [
    "sender" => $email,
    "to" => "abc@gmail.com",
    "subject" => "Subject",
    "textBody" => $query,
];

try {
    $message = new Message($mail_options);
    $message->send();
} catch (InvalidArgumentException $e) {
    echo "not send";

}?>
```

my logs

```
INFO     2014-07-31 21:40:31,711 mail_stub.py:142] MailService.Send
  From: bca@gmail.com
  To: abc0@gmail.com
  Subject: Subject
  Body:
    Content-type: text/plain
    Data length: 3
INFO     2014-07-31 21:40:31,711 mail_stub.py:305] You are not currently sending out real email.  If you have sendmail installed you can use it by using the server with --enable_sendmail.
```

But [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/mail/) it is not given to install any external application they just instructed to use GAE API to send mail.

**What should I do?**

**Is there any problem with my PHP code?**

Comment: the sender's email address has to be an administrators. Is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting that error because you are running it on localhost, if you deploy it to your appengine cloud and set the "send from" to the administrator's email linked to that project like Paul said, it should work. When I tested it with localhost, I got the same error but when deployed, it worked fine.

Comment: thanks,is there any way to change the sender email? because i want to take the email address from my form and send the mail to my id from that email address.

Comment: The 'from' email definitely needs to be the project's email. You could still have it pull from your form through POST but you'd have to enter that same project email each time. One idea is that you could leave the 'from' email hard coded to be your project email, and then copy the email from your form somewhere in the email's body or even subject.